# How to differentiate between separate meanings of て form?

Tags: grammar, usage, て-form, parsing

Sometimes the て form has an adverbial meaning like: 重ねて  or 歩いて行く and sometimes it functions as a way to connect two sentences. Is there an easy way to differentiate between what meaning is being used?

Comment: Context. Sorry if that's doesn't sound helpful, but it's the only  answer to so many questions in Japanese.

Comment: Please look at this answer by <https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/12/andry>. It helped me. Hope it helps you too. <https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11301/29313>

Comment: ^ いやその回答の例文はあんまり・・・特に対話文のとこは・・・

Answer (score 2):

If there is a comma after the first verb in te-form, you're lucky, because it *tends* to be sequential actions ("V1 and V2", "V1, then V2"). The first verb [can be a reason](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html) for the second verb.

> - 朝起きて、顔を洗う。　(sequential actions)
> - 彼女に会って、話をします。　(sequential actions)
> - 電車が遅れて、遅刻した。　(sequential actions / reason)

If there is no comma, it can *also* refer to methods or surrounding events/situations, "V2 while V1" or "V2 by/with V1-ing". The correct meaning depends on the context.

> - 急いで顔を洗う。　(situation)
> - 歩いて学校に行く。　(method)
> - 朝起きて顔を洗う。　(sequential actions)

"Context" may be a disappointing answer, but English also has many context-dependent words that confuses people who learn English as the second language. For example, "as he speaks" means both "while he speaks" and "because he speaks". "She must be a pro" means both "she has to be a pro" and "she is certainly a pro". You can soon get used to such ambiguous constructions once you've understood the possible meanings.