# Usage of てーform in this example sentence

Tags: grammar

食事は良く噛んで、食べましょう。

The first clause is to tell the listener to chew their meal carefully. The second clause is more of "Let's eat". What does the で do in this sentence? I understand it is to join two clauses and that て form has many usage, but for this context, can I assume it is a sequence of event?

E.g. Speaker tells the listener to chew his meal carefully, followed by suggesting to eat?

Comment: related?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3786/7810

Comment: @broccoliforest i am not too sure, because if the comma is used to separate and give a space between the two clause, what role does the で play before the comma? Thanks for the link though!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74775/5010

Comment: @naruto I assume in this case, if the て form in my sentence means "while", can I say the sentence is something like "Let's eat while making sure that we chew our food carefully"? Am I right to say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 食事は良く噛んで食べましょう。

This type of te-form adverbially describes how the second verb (食べる) is done. [This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38769/5010) is related. Similar examples include:

- 歩いて学校に行く
  to go to school by foot (not "to walk and then go to school")
- ナイフを使って紙を切る
  to cut paper using a knife (not "to use a knife and then cut paper")

In your case the second verb is less important than the first verb, so the sentence can be translated like "Let's chew well when you eat a meal."

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to clarify why "食べましょう" is not "let's eat" in this context, and more of "when you eat" in your example

Comment: @DK4739 It depends on the context, i.e., which verb is the message. "Let's use your knife (to cut the paper)" vs "Let's cut paper (with a knife)".