# Is て-form used here to concatenate phrases?

Tags: grammar, て-form

The following phrase is taken from [an NHK News article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012440191000/k10012440191000.html):

「...。そして国が出すお金を使って、働いている人が仕事を続けることができるようにしてほしいと会社に言います」

Why is 使う used in te-form? Just to concatenate the two sentences? Or is it some way to say "by using"?

Comment: Your analysis of "by using" is correct. See these links (and others): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38769/%e3%81%a6-form-and-adverbial-meaning  / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/75105/usage-of-%e3%81%a6%e3%83%bcform-in-this-example-sentence/75172#75172

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks, that's it. Next time I'll search for 使って, not only て(too many results).