# てならない　vs て（は）ならない

Tags: grammar

I struggle with these two expressions which mean two different things... especially knowing that the は can be omitted.

- このケーキを食べて(は)ならない。(I) must not eat that cake.
- このケーキを食べてならない。(I) cannot help eating that cake. I am dying to eat
  that cake.

Apart from the context, any cue on how to distinguish them ?

The first one, I see it, as "About eating the cake, wont do" thus, I must not eat it !
The second one, I dont really know how to deconstruct it.

Comment: Related: [～てたまらない、～てならない、～しようがない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59585/43676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically both are the same and should be considered as a set phrase. [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/#jn-165275) has an entry for this:

> １ （「てならない」の形で）その事について抑えようのない気持ちを表す。「話の続きが気になって―◦ない」「おかしくて―◦ない」
>
> ２ （多く「てはならない」の形で）禁止を表す。「絶対に忘れては―◦ない」「許可なしに入室しては―◦ない」

#1 corresponds to your second example and #2 the first.

In terms of how to determine the usage, as stated in [this](https://tanosuke.com/tenaranai) and should be clear from the definition, "can't help" meaning is preceded by a word expressing feelings (emphasis mine).

> **感情や感覚の形容詞を使う。**
> 一人称に使う。三人称の場合、文末が推量の形になる。
> 少し古い言い方。
> **動詞は自然にそうなる自発動詞が多い: 思える・思い出される・思われる・感じられる・泣ける・見える・気になる・悔やまれるなどです。**

As such, your second example is not quite idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer.